# $db undefined when using model from helper in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model, helper

I want to have a simple helper which records one hit in my database. I have created a $CI instance and attempt to access the model like this...

```
$CI->load->model('stats_model');
$CI->stats_model->set_hit();
```

But i get an error in the model..

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Stats_model::$db
Filename: models/stats_model.php
Line Number: 16
```

Line 16 is a simple...

```
$this->db->select('*');
```

I got the idea to do this from this link http://blog.avinash.com.np/2010/07/01/talk-to-the-database-from-a-helper-codeigniter/

I have tried $CI->db... instead of $this->db in the model but still no luck, any ideas?

HELPER

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

function check_hit() {
//stuff that uses CI
$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('user_agent');
if ($CI->agent->is_robot()) {
    return FALSE;
} else {

    //check for a 12 hour cookie
    $check = $CI->input->cookie('stat');

    if ($check == false) {
        //insert a database entry
        $CI->load->model('Stats_model');
        $CI->Stats_model->set_hit();

        //set a cookie

        $cookie = array(
            'name' => 'stat',
            'value' => '1',
            'expire' => '43200'
        );

       // $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
}
}

check_hit();
?>
```

MODEL

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Stats_model extends Model {

function Stats_model() {
// Call the Model constructor
    parent::Model();
}

function set_hit() {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $this->db->select('unique_visitors');
    $this->db->from('daily_stats');
    $this->db->where('date', $date);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $date_rows = $query->num_rows();
    $result = $query->row();
    $visits = $result->unique_visitors;
    $visits++;

    $data = array(
        'unique_visitors' => $visits,
        'date' => $date
    );

    if ($date_rows == 1) {
        $this->db->where('date', $date);
        $this->db->update('daily_stats', $data);
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('daily_stats', $data);
    }
}

}
?>
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but you are loading the database driver, right?

Comment: Its being loaded in the autoload config file. If I try to load it again in the helper using ... $CI->load->library('database'); i get an error ... Unable to load the requested class: database

Comment: No, if it's in autoload, it should be fine.  I just wanted to check.

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered my question. I never found an answer but I think it was a blessing in disguise because now i am using the Gapi (google analytics php api) as a helper and puling daily stats on a cron job. A much better cleaner solution!

Answer (score 0):

This part was a little confusing for me a while back. This seemed to work.

```
//load the CI instance
$this->ci =& get_instance();


//run a db get
$this->ci->db->get('mytable');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its still not working for me. I have tried putting $this->ci =& get_instance(); in the model function but i get the same error.